# What are these equivalent data types of C in Java?

Tags: java, c, types, biginteger, bit

Say I have very big numbers. I know in C we could declare:

```
long long int // What is equivalent of this in Java?

long double   // and this?
```

Thanks.

Comment: for primatives: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/02.html otherwise use BigDecimal and BigInteger

Comment: It depends what C you're trying to translate from.  Java primitive types have fixed precision across all platforms, but `long long int` and `long double` have different meanings in C depending on your platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in C, a `long double` and `long long int` use varying representations on different hardware and compilers.  Many compilers consider `long double` to be the same as `double`—or might give an error.

Similarly, `long long` has limited support on 16- and 32-bit compilers and especially such platforms.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) we can see that in Java,

a 64 bit = long, 32 bit = int.

Therefore, your `long long int` in C in a 64 bit linux environment produces a 64 bit int which is equivalent to long in Java. In Windows, 64 bits is _int64.

however, long double is a newer feature and extends the usual length of double and has no primitive equivalent in Java

Answer (score 3):

There is no native equivalent in java. You should check out the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.